# Making Changes Between Two Databases ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, migration, database-migration

I'm working on a project in which we have two versions of an MVC App, the live, and the dev versions, I've made changes to the dev version and added tables and data, etc.

Is there any way to migrate these changes onto the live version without losing all data(i.e. just regenerating the database).

I've already tried just rebuilding the database but we lose all data that was previously stored( as obviously we are essentially deleting the old database and rebuilding it).

tl;dr

How do I migrate my dev version of an mvc app along with any new tables to the live version of an mvc app with missing models and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to migrate your changes from your dev instance to your production instance; to do so you must create SQL scripts that update your production database with the changes. This may be accomplished by manually writing the scripts or by using tools to generate the scripts for you. However you go about it, you will need scripts to update your database (well, you could perform manual updates via the tooling of your database, but this is not desirable, as you want the updates to occur in a short time window, and you want this to happen reliably and repeatably).

The easiest way that I know of to do this is to use tools like SQL Compare (for schema updates) or SQL Data Compare (for data updates). These are from Redgate, but they cost a fair bit of money. They are well worth they price, and most companies I've worked with are happy to pay for licenses. However, you may not want to shell out for them personally. To use these tools, you connect them to source and destination databases, and they analyze the differences between the databases (schematically or data) and produce SQL scripts. These scripts may then be run manually or by the tools themselves.

Ideally, when you work on your application, you should be producing these scripts as you go along. That way when it comes time to update your environments, you may simply run the scripts you have. It is worth taking the time to include this in your build process, so database scripts get included in your builds. You should write your scripts so they are idempotent, meaning that you can run them multiple times and the end result will be the same (the database updated to the desired schema and data).

One may of managing this is creating a DBVersions table in your database. This table includes all your script updates. For example you could have a table like the following (this is SQL Server 2008 dialect):

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DBVersions] (
    [CaseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateExecutedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DBVersions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [CaseID] ASC
 )
) ON [PRIMARY]`

CaseID refers to the case (or issue) number of the feature or bug that requires the SQL update. Your build process can check this table to see if the script has already been run. If not, it runs it. This is useful if you cannot write your scripts in a way that allows them to be run more than once. If all your scripts can be run an unbounded number of times, then this table is not strictly necessary, though it could still be useful to reduce the need to run a large number of script every time a deployment is done.

Here are links to the Redgate tools. There may be many other tools out there, but I've had a very good experience with these.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your deployment strategy and this is more of a workflow that your team need to embrace. If regenerating the live database from scratch it can take awhile depending how big the database size is. I don't see a need to do this in most scenarios.

You would only need to separate out database schema object and data row scripts. The live database version should have its database schema objects scripted out and stored in a repository. When a developer is working on a new functionality, he/she will need to make those changes against the database scripts in the repository. If there is a need to make changes to the database rows then the developer will also need to check in the data row scripts in the repository. On a daily deployment the live database version can be compared against what is checked in the repository and pushed to make it in sync.

On our side we use tools such as RedGate [Schema Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do the database migration from the dev version to our intended target version.